# How to Rotate image after tapped in uiscrollview?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, rotation, xcode4.5

```
- (void)configureView

{
  lblwelcome.text=@"Welcome To Gallery World";
    for (UIImageView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *addAcc = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Zoom"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(zoomEnabled)];

    UIBarButtonItem *delAcc = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Rotate"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(rotateEnabled)];

    NSArray *arrBtns = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:addAcc,delAcc, nil];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = arrBtns;

    categoryScrollX=30;
    categoryScrollY=30;




    [scr.delegate self];
    scr.frame = self.view.frame;
    for (UIImageView *subview in scr.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    height = 200;
    width = 400;
    pos_y =0;
    pos_x =0;
    int idx=0;
    CGFloat x=0;
    switch (_itemNo) {
        case 0:
            for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
            {//imageView.frame = CGRectMake(categoryScrollX, categoryScrollY, (self.view.frame.size.width/4)-25, self.view.frame.size.width/4-5);
                UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(categoryScrollX, categoryScrollY, (self.view.frame.size.width/4)-25, self.view.frame.size.width/4-5)];
                [image setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"e1%d.png",i]]];
                [scr addSubview:image];
                x+=320;
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
                tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                tapGesture.delegate = self;
                image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [image addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
//                [image.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor]];
//                [image.layer setBorderWidth: 0.9];
//                image.layer.MasksToBounds = false;
//                image.layer.ShadowColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
//                image.layer.ShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
//                image.layer.ShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2.5f);
//                image.clipsToBounds = NO;

                CALayer* layer = [image layer];
                [layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
                [image setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                [layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];


                scr.minimumZoomScale = scr.frame.size.width / imgview.frame.size.width;
                scr.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
                [scr setZoomScale:scr.minimumZoomScale];
                scrollPosition++;
                currentIndex++;
                if(scrollPosition>4)
                {
                    categoryScrollY = categoryScrollY+self.view.frame.size.width/4+12;
                    scrollPosition=0;
                    currentIndex = currentIndex+scrollPosition;
                    categoryScrollX=30;
                }
                else
                {
                    categoryScrollX= (categoryScrollX+self.view.frame.size.width/4)-6;
                }


            }

            scr.pagingEnabled=YES;
            scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*5, 300);


             _detailDescriptionLabel.text=@"Accessories";
             self.title=@"Accessories";
            [self.view addSubview:scr];

            break;
```

.....following by other cases with the above way with different images....

Above is my configure view and am just adding some dynamic images in UiScrollview and i have added tap guesture on each images....with the following

```
-(void)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)rec{

    for (UIImageView *subview in scr.subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UIView *img = [rec view];
    img.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:img];

}
```

now what i want is after tap i want to give rotation effect to that image..
am just beginners for this Xcode environment and as well as iOS development.

some how i just succeeded to show images in uiscrollview..but after googled so much i couldn't find a good guidance for rotating the image.so can any one help me out to give rotation to uiimageview image in uiscrollview after the image is tapped?

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,

```
-(IBAction)ButtonAction:(id)sender{
    CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
        fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
        fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
        fullRotation.duration = 1;
        fullRotation.repeatCount = 1;
        [imageview.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];

}
```

take one button and give action(call this mathod) for that button.

Comment: thanx for quick response..but i want to ask you as am totally beginner can u please tell me where to add this code////sorry for silly question

Comment: ok i have done as u said..but its gave compile time error as follows:- Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CABasicAnimation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DetailViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: i have already this in my .m file #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "QuartzCore/CALayer.h"  anything else i forget?

Comment: i just implemented as u said

Comment: SO ,,u cant help me more on that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26851/discussion-between-sunny-and-bhavik-kama)

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the imageView using the following code :

`imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);`